# Run a task depending on parameter on azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

I have a job template that is used by many pipelines, however I want to run a particular task only when a parameter as a value. How can I do that.

To keep it simple see below example part of a template only run the copy file task if sourcefolder and targetfolder are not empty.

Any suggestions how to write this condition?

```
parameters:
  sourceFolder: ''         
  targetFolder: ''

jobs:
 - job: 'AAA Job'


 steps: 
    # ONLY RUN BELOW TASK IF SOURCEFOLDER AND TARGETFOLDER ARE NOT EMPTY
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy file'
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: ${{ parameters.sourceFolder}
      TargetFolder: ${{ parameters.targetFolder}}
      OverWrite: true
```

UPDATE  (below gives an error "unxpected value")

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  condition: ${{ if and(ne(parameters.SourceFolder,''), ne(parameters.TargetFolder,''))}}
  displayName: 'Copy Google Services Json from ${{ parameters.SourceFolder }} to  ${{ parameters.TargetFolder }}'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: ${{ parameters.SourceFolder }}
    TargetFolder: ${{ parameters.TargetFolder }}
    OverWrite: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add below script to your template yaml file.

```
- ${{ if and(ne(parameters.sourceFolder,''), ne(parameters.targetFolder,''))}}:
```

So the pipeline should like this:

```
parameters:
  sourceFolder: ''         
  targetFolder: ''

jobs:
- job: 'AAA Job'

  steps: 
  - ${{ if and(ne(parameters.sourceFolder,''), ne(parameters.targetFolder,''))}}:
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy file'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: ${{ parameters.sourceFolder}
        TargetFolder: ${{ parameters.targetFolder}}
        OverWrite: true
```

You can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion) for more information.

Comment: It means "not equal"

Comment: thank you I was looking for the definitions of those .

Comment: hi there I need to apply the condition to a task. but I get an error "unexpected value" see question update. Any suggestions . I have googled and cannot establish if I can do that in a task

Comment: try this: `condition: and(ne(parameters.SourceFolder,''), ne(parameters.TargetFolder,''))`

Comment: Lu- MSFT Thanks for you help that does not work. I know that parameters must have the ${{ parameters.Whatever }} I think we are getting the brackets wrong. I will google more..

Comment: I  get "Unrecognized value: 'parameters'. Located at position 8 within expression: and(ne(parameters.SourceFolder,''), ne(parameters.TargetFolder,'')).